# Trying to access data from a google forms gsheet, from a local Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

Yes, similar questions are all over this site. My issue is the responses on the Gsheet contain info that would GDDPR relevant and so can't be published for public access.

I need a way to read the data without giving access to anyone who manages to find the sheet online. I have tried to sync the gsheet to my local Google Drive, however, I don't know how to access that data from excel without manually converting the gsheet.

The reason is:

I have a consent webform, users fill it out, it takes their email address. I have an excel VBA module that will loop through the email address, check the date the were provided and send an update to each user when so many days have passed. the excel sheet will be run each day at close of business.

I need to either read or copy the data from the gsheet so I can run my mailer code. How do I do this, from within Excel? The Person using this is not savvy enough to be manually importing data, I want them literally to open excel and push a button. So I need my VBA to go to my local google drive, and either copy over the data from the gsheet or read it in place and get the email addresses it needs.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Would it not be easier to implement the autoresponder directly in the Google Sheet using [Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)? Also see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Comment: Hey, that was first thought, but I have 3 different types of response emails based on the data in their Forms responses and dates, each of the emailed has different attachments to be included as well.  (Pre-appointment info, Appointment reminder with Covid safety info and Post appointment follow up with Info PDF). There's a lot of Case Select and loop statements in the excel code.

Comment: I cannot see why that would make a difference. You may want to do some research into the many emailer scripts. You can run such scripts periodically on a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).

Comment: Ok, SO I took your advice, I learnt how to do it Apps Script. It works. BUT, I've set up a time driven trigger, however it only runs if the sheet is left open. I need it to run at the designated time regardless of whether the sheet is open or not. I'm guessing its something to do with the line; " var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()", as when it is closed there is no active sheet? Or do I have to deploy the script somehow first?

Comment: A script that runs on a time-driven trigger will work the same regardless of whether or not a user has the spreadsheet open, and in fact has no easy way to tell whether there are active users.

Comment: Ok, SO I have two issues then, though one might solve the other. Since reopening my code I found it doesn't run due to a type mismatch in the line :var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 13);       -   Error 
Exception: The parameters (String,number,String,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.

Comment: Please post your new question in a new topic. You should only ask [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).